# 'int' and 'str' mistake

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtl7B.png)

```
bank_account = None
highest = 0

for account, amount in accounts.items():
    
    if amount > highest:           -------------< 
        bank_account = account
        highest = account 
        
print(bank_acount, highest)
```

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

how can I alter my code to make it works

Comment: Cast the string to an int. Something like int(amount) > highest.

Comment: `highest = account` Presumably you meant to assign `highest = amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either 'account' or 'highest' is a string, you need to determine which one and adjust your code.

If the string is the string form of a number, i.e. "1", you can use `int("1")` to get the int form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a typo in the line that says:

> highest = account

Looks like you wanted that line to say

> highest = amount